# How to get true fullscreen in VirtualBox with Windows guest?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, fullscreen, osx-el-capitan

This is what I don't want:

[image: This is what i dont want]

Is there some way to make guest os fullscreen and scaled?

I'm using Virtualbox 5.1.2 with a Windows guest and an OS X El Capitan host.

Comment: Install the Guest OS Addition and it will scale accordingly to the full screen.

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me where I can find them? Virtualbox website says that I can download some guest additions update for linux.

Comment: To summarize: Click on "Devices" and choose "Install Guest Addition CD Image" and then the Guest OS will see the CD. Just install it and restart the Guest OS.

Comment: @Darius seems like a valid answer. Wny hot post it as such?

Comment: @LPChip Got distracted by kids :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Manoj Sawai's [youtube link](http://youtube.com/watch?v=vi53zKcvgXU) (for visual guide)

The summary of what needs to be done:

- Click on "Devices" and choose "Install Guest Addition CD Image"
- Then Guest OS will see the Guest Addition CD
- Simply start the installation and restart the Guest OS.

Note: Although you have the full screen and view - some of the Windows Shortcut may not work (as it is intercepted by the Mac OS X)

If you want "true" full screen and Windows experience then you may want to consider bootcamp.